# How do I return a value stored in the <head> section

Tags: protractor, var, head

I am trying to return the top.window.XSS value from the html below using Protractor.  I am able to get the "script type" but not the var(s) below. What is the preferred method; I am using the tagName locator?

```
            element.all(by.tagName('script')).getAttribute('type').then(function(array) {
console.log(array);
});


<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<!-- 195780 -->
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store">
<link href="/ibm/console/css/ISCTheme/en/Styles.css" rel="styleSheet"    type="text/css"><link href="/ibm/console/css/ISCTheme/Styles_common.css" rel="styleSheet" type="text/css">
    <title>
        HQD400 - IBM Navigator for i
    </title>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../../auiruntime8106/dojo/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ibm/console/iscTabView.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentLan="en-US";
    var expandStr = "Expand"; //@ddsuA
    var collapseStr = "Collapse";
    var reloadStr = "Reload";
    var XSS='wabLN6a93vPz1cNyZNW9mKZ';
    top.window.XSS="wabLN6a93vPz1cNyZNW9mKZ";
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below option

```
ele = element.all(by.css('script[type="text/javascript"]').last()

console.log(ele.getAttribute('value')); //This prints your var's
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Hi Madhan-
Thank you for the response; I am very new to Protractor.
How do I resolve this output from the console.log statement?

ElementFinder {
  browser_:
   ProtractorBrowser {
     controlFlow: [Function],
     schedule: [Function],
     setFileDetector: [Function],
     getExecutor: [Function],
     getSession: [Function],
     getCapabilities: [Function]...

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but this time nothing is returned.

Comment: Output is now:  ElementFinder {
  browser_:
   ProtractorBrowser {
     controlFlow: [Function],
     schedule: [Function],
     setFileDetector: [Function],
     getExecutor: [Function],
     getSession: [Function],
     getCapabilities: [Function],
     quit: [Function],
     actions: [Function],
     touchActions: [Function],
     executeScript: [Function],
....

Comment: share your implementation of the answer provided